# Запуск скрипта при нажатом чекбоксе

Tags: javascript

Что нужно поменять в скрипте, чтобы он срабатывал не только при нажатии не чекбокс, но и когда у чекбокса при загрузке уже стоит checked

```js
 $('.select-box-options .has-input input').on('change', function() {
  if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
   var inputValue = $(this).parent().find('.input-text').html();
   $(this).parents('.form-search-group').append('<div class="size selected-wrap"><div class="selected">' + inputValue + '</div></div>');
  } else {
   var inputValue = $(this).parent().find('.input-text').text(),
       arraySelected = $(this).parents('.form-search-group').find('.selected-wrap');

   arraySelected.each(function() {
    if ( $(this).text() == inputValue ) {
     $(this).remove();
    }
   });
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
$('.select-box-options .has-input input').trigger("change");
```

Это должно вызвать событие `change` у чекбокса, на которое вы подписались, вызвав

`$('.select-box-options .has-input input').on('change', ...)`

так же можно выцвать этот оператор в конце цепочки вызовов селектора, вот так:

```
$('.select-box-options .has-input input').on('change', function() {

     ....

}).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло